# How to update kernel to 3.19 on 14.04 with i915 Intel graphics?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel, intel-graphics

On 14.04.2 LTS (amd64), I need to update the Linux kernel to 3.19+ (because it adds support for some hardware I have). The computer uses EFI and has an integrated Intel Graphics controller. lspci output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
```

I need to use a lowlatency kernel. The system works perfectly with the default kernels 3.16.0-33-generic and 3.16.0-33-lowlatency.

I tried installing version 3.19 to 3.19.2 from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/, as well as linux-image-3.19.0-10-lowlatency_3.19.0-10.10_amd64.deb from [the vivid repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/linux-image-3.19.0-10-lowlatency).

With the kernels from mainline, the computer freezes after loading the kernel, sometimes on a black screen, sometimes after displaying some text messages.

With the kernel from vidid, the computer sometimes freezes on the splash screen (but with the animation continuing), sometimes boots successfully, but very slowly. I'm even able to log in, but everything is slow and dialogs appear to tell that internal errors happened. Sometimes it freezes after logging in successfully.

With all kernels, booting with nomodeset (or in recovery mode) works perfectly, but then X uses the vesa driver instead of the intel one. The log then states:

```
[     8.916] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[     8.916] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
```

The installed version of the xorg-video-intel package is xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-utopic 2:2.99.914-1~exp1ubuntu4.2~trusty1. Could the normal boot be failing because it was built for an older kernel?

What should I do to make this computer work with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but with a 3.19+ Linux kernel and with the graphics driver working properly?

Comment: Do you know how to debug kernel problems? If not, learn, because that's what you should do.